# Delete all messages from a channel using Discord

Tags: go, discord

I'm trying to delete all messages from a channel using discord bot, but the only command to delete messages that i found is
 `s.ChannelMessageDelete(m.ChannelID, m.ID)`

it only deletes 1 message at time, i would like to clear all
which command can i use to do it?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you'll only be able to delete 100 at a time. If you want to delete "everything", you need to keep fetching new batches of message ids

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** As the commenter noted, you can see this will only delete 100 messages at a time in the source code. If you want to delete all messages, you'll have to call this function in chunks of 100 messages.

From [the source code](https://github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo/blob/master/restapi.go#L1699-L1720) and the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo#Session.ChannelMessagesBulkDelete), you can use `ChannelMessagesBulkDelete`:

```golang
// ChannelMessagesBulkDelete bulk deletes the messages from the channel for the provided messageIDs.
// If only one messageID is in the slice call channelMessageDelete function.
// If the slice is empty do nothing.
// channelID : The ID of the channel for the messages to delete.
// messages  : The IDs of the messages to be deleted. A slice of string IDs. A maximum of 100 messages.
func (s *Session) ChannelMessagesBulkDelete(channelID string, messages []string) (err error) {
   ...
}
```